# Graph representations of complex sklearn models

Tags: scikit-learn

With pipelines and feature unions, `sklearn` models can quickly become pretty complex. See, for example, [this post](http://zacstewart.com/2014/08/05/pipelines-of-featureunions-of-pipelines.html). However, I couldn't find any function or library that visualizes these models
[image: example of a complex model]

Can someone point me to such a function?